# Getting VS Code To Function More Like PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, console, visual-studio-code

I'm spending more time working in PowerShell lately and I've found I really enjoy the form and function of [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) for this work over the native PowerShell ISE, except for one small bit:

**In the ISE** I can call and explore variables, arrays, and hashes and other entities in the code I'm currently working on in the command line of the ISE, but in VS Code, using either the PowerShell Integrated console or the powershell.exe console, I get no such ability.

**For instance:**

In the ISE I've built a hash table and am learning the syntax for referencing it by trying various things in the console, and by "running" the code, even if it is just declaring and building the hashtable, I can then reference this and explore it in the console:

[image: PowerShell ISE with some code and output]

When I attempt to do this in VS Code (same code, run the script in either of the consoles), I receive this error basically noting the array I'm trying to explore doesn't exist:

[image: powershell console output in VS Code]

How could I get a similar function in VS Code? Or is this even possible?

Perhaps most of my problem is that I'm having trouble describing this in a way Google "understands" and so I haven't been able to find any similar questions online.

Comment: Not sure about the answer to this.  You might want to ask in the Vscode channel in this Slack.  Some of the devs hang out there.  http://slack.poshcode.org/

Comment: I'm not experiencing this issue. Just created a variable, ran debug, then was able to access that variable in the terminal window.

Comment: @root I had not tried the debug until earlier today, after I submitted this question, and saw it did that. Now I'm trying to figure out if this can be the "default" mode of the console when working with PS files in VS Code.

Comment: How were you executing other than F5 (debug)? I'm not versed in VSC

Comment: I was executing the script in the console: .\scriptname.ps1 <enter> I haven't used debugging since at least a couple programming classes in junior college.

Comment: @music2myear Ah. ISE's "Run Script" essentially means "Start Debugging".

Comment: @root It appears so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're not dot sourcing the script, you're just passing the script path (per your comment on the original post)

**What you're doing:**  `.\script.ps1` (just stating a path, nothing calling the script to run it)

**What you should be doing:** `. .\script.ps1` (dot sourcing to load the script contents into the session).

**Here's me replicating your issue:**

[image]

**Here's it working:**

[image]

1. First line is me clearing the variable from the session
2. Second line is confirmation that the variable is replicating your issue (expected, since the variable doesn't exist at that moment)
3. Third line is dot sourcing the script which contains the below block (same as your screenshot) to replicate how you're approaching it
4. Running the exact same hashtable lookup resulting in the same output you're receiving from ISE

Script block in `testHash.ps1`:

```
$hash_agencyOffices = @{
    Agency1 = @{
        Agency1 = @(
            "Aberdeen"
            "Sacramento"
            "Dallas"
            "Long Beach"
            "Tampa"
            "Seattle"
            "Vancouver"
        )
    }
    Agency2 = @{
        SubAgency1 = @(
            "Aberdeen"
            "Sacramento"
            "Dallas"
            "Long Beach"
            "Tampa"
            "South Bend"
            "Stevenson"
            "Tumwater"
            "Vancouver"
        )
        SubAgency2 = @(
            "Dallas"
            "Seattle"
            "Vancouver"
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this going into debug?

Comment: this is replicating the process, not calling F5 to debug / run the current open file in editor. Check my edit for full explanation of what you're doing

Comment: you can see in my console that I'm not loading the editor contents at all in between commands... I'm clearing the variable to get back to zero, **dot sourcing** the script file containing the variable to load it into the session, then working with the variable as needed =]

Comment: and to that same point, in your ISE screenshot, the last thing loaded before you call the hashtable variable is your editor contents, give that you can see your hashtable as the last thing ran in the console prior to you calling the indexes ;-)

Comment: at the end of the day, your try in VSCode failed because you didn't load the hashtable into your session, while your ISE attempt worked because you did load it into the session prior. In either IDE, you would experience the same result if you were running it the same exact way =]

Comment: I'll check all that tomorrow when I'm back at my desk. I'm reasonably certain I'm running the latest versions of VS Code and the Powershell extension.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "dot referencing" you're doing. I see what you've done, I've just never done it or heard of it. Second, the "exact same way" only really works if there is the same button or obvious control to accomplish the same thing. VS Code \= PowerShell ISE. There is no big green "play" button in the VS Code toolbar. So being informed of what dot referencing is and that it is necessary to replicate the play button effect in the ISE is very helpful, but requires some definition before it becomes "exactly the same thing".

Comment: For sure! You should be fine, I think that you ended up giving yourself a false positive in ISE tbh. The only way to load a file's contents into the current session is by dot sourcing the path, as far as I'm aware. Happy scripting!

Comment: F5 is the same command in both ISE and Code though, even though Code may not have that green "play" button on top of it's editor window. The same big green play button can be found in Code in the debug pane on the left hand side though. Some more info on dot sourcing: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/08/10/how-to-reuse-windows-powershell-functions-in-scripts/

Comment: Also to my point, when you press the play button in ISE, you're running the current contents of the editor window, not loading the file. If the file is saved before hand, you'll see just the file name in the console when you press F5 (same as in Code). Otherwise, you'll see the editor contents like you do in your screenshot. I think you'll find that in this scenario, Code and ISE behave the exact same from a fresh session, even though that play button may not be as prominently visible in Code.

Comment: Thanks for educating me on this. Using the dot sourcing I was able to replicate the behavior.

Comment: Nice!! Happy to help! Enjoy working in VS Code with Powershell, it's only going to keep getting better! MS is putting their Powershell development efforts all into VS Code and cross platform compatibility right now and has stated that ISE is only going to see updates on an as-needed basis at this point, so it's exciting to see where Code is going to end up. Once they add PSReadLine support and get the syntax highlighting on par with ISE, it'll be everything that ISE is and then some (to me at least). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

[VS Code is open source.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) What you're trying to do doesn't appear to be supported *now*, so if you want a feature like that, patches are always welcome. :)

Comment: I hoped that wasn't the answer, but feared it might.

Comment: Oh, I think I might have just figured it out. Oy. PowerShell ISE is basically in a perpetual state of Debug. Starting a Debug Session in VS Code seemed to give me the functions I want. Now to see if there's ways to make this the "default" console mode.

Comment: VS Code may be open source, but it's totally capable of doing this if you load the variable into the session the same way in either editor. i.e. you can run the open file ("debug" w/ F5), highlight the entire hashtable and press F8 to run the selection (works the same in both editors), or **dot source** the saved script file to load it's contents into the session (key term is dot sourcing here, i.e. placing a dot [period] then a space then the path to the script file)

Comment: Thankfully, nferrell pointed out the connections I was missing and now I can work in VS Code in pretty much the same way I did the PS IDE.